# Extend CRUD with column from other model/array in ATK4

Tags: php, atk4

In atk4 I like to extend CRUD with one column which is a lookup in an array of an available column in the model. It's to get the category name (catshop) of which the catshop_id is already available. But the catshop is only available as array.

The model is:

```
class Model_CatLink extends Model_Table {
  public $table='catlink';
  function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('catshop_id');
    $this->addField('margin_ratio');
  }
}
```

And on the page I have:

```
$catshop=array(1=>'cat1',2=>'another cat 2',...,123=>'top cat'); 
$c=$p->add('CRUD');
$m=$this->add('Model_CatLink');
$c->setModel($m);
```

Now the grid shows the catshop_id and margin_ratio field. With catshop_id I want to lookup the category title available in $catshop. This $catshop array is actually retrieved from another mysql platform so not possible to join.

**How to extend the crud with the catshop column?** 
What I tried so far is to extend the model itself with addExpression... couldn't get it working.

I thought something like this, first to add this to the model:

```
$self=$this;
$this->addExpression('catshop')->set(function($select) use ($self){
    return $self->catshop[$self->get('catshop_id')];
});
```

And then on the page to pass the $catshop to the model:

```
$catshop=array(1=>'cat1',2=>'another cat 2',...,123=>'top cat'); 
$c=$p->add('CRUD');
$m=$this->add('Model_CatLink');
$m->catshop=$catshop;
$c->setModel($m);
```

Then I thought to add the values to the model just before the $c->setModel($m) although I'm not sure how to proceed this.

The result I'm looking for is a CRUD which shows the catshop string and also allows to change the catshop_id with a dropdown build from the catshop array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend CRUD, you need to extend Grid which CRUD is actively using. Alternatively you can extend model loading.

## Option 1: In Grid:

```
class MyGrid extends Grid {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->add('myfield','category');
    }
    funciton format_myfield($field){
        $this->current_row[$field]=
            $this->model->lookupCategory($this->current_row[$field]);

        // use current_row_html[] if you want HTML output
    }
}
```

Then when you create CRUD you need to specify this:

```
$c=$this->add('CRUD',array('grid_class'=>'MyGrid'));
```

## Option 2: In model:

Your alternative is afterLoad inside model:

```
class Model_CatLink extends Model_Table {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addExpression('category')->set('undefined'); // nothing by default

        $this->addHook('afterLoad',$this);
    }
    function afterLoad(){
        $this['category']=$this->lookupCategory($this['category_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm studying the options. Option 1 will solve it as formatting while option 2 will already solve it in the model. How to get the dropdown in the form part of CRUD when adding/modifiying a record? With hasMany() it will automatically do both. Here the grid part is solved, so should I do addField('dropdown','category') on the $c->form myself or should I think of extending the Field_Reference?

Comment: To add a dropdown to the form part of CRUD I used $m->getField('catshop_id')->datatype('list')->setValueList($catshop); and it's updating database properly. Now I will try out the suggested option1 to list the corresponding category in the grid.